# Vlookup in table to copy multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to get my VBA code to do a vlookup match in a table with 3 columns and when it finds a match it should copy the right sheets to another file.

I have a userform which a username has to be entered in. Then it matches this username (column A) to a cell with sheetnames in (column C). How can I define this vlookup to match and then copy the multiple sheets. And how should I format the sheetnames in column C?

My table looks like this right now:
A: User (for example "Alexandra")
B: Password (for example "Test 1")
C: Sheets (for example "Sheet 1, Sheet 2")

Thanks!

EDIT:

My current code for the password authorization, this is based on a Userform:

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim Id As String, pw As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If Len(Trim(txtLogin)) = 0 Then
txtLogin.SetFocus
MsgBox "Gebruikersnaam moet ingevuld zijn."
Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Trim(txtPassword)) = 0 Then
txtPassword.SetFocus
MsgBox "Wachtwoord moet ingevuld zijn."
Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Worksheets("PW")
Id = LCase(Me.txtLogin)

Set aCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=Id, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'~~> If match found
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
RowNo = aCell.Row
'~~> Rest of your code. For example if the password is
'~~> Stored in Col B then
'~~> Replace txtPassword with the actual name of password textbox
If Me.txtPassword = aCell.Offset(, 1) Then
Call CopySheets()
Unload Me
Else
MsgBox "De ingevoerde gegevens zijn onjuist. Probeer het opnieuw.", vbOKOnly
End If
Else '<~~ If not found
MsgBox "De ingevoerde gegevens zijn onjuist. Probeer het opnieuw.", vbOKOnly
End If
CleanExit:
Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Now I need the code to have the sheets copied based on the input in txtLogin.

Comment: If you have code you should include it in your question.  Exactly which part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: Code has been added. The copying code with input from the txtlogin vlookup is giving me problems. I don't know how to start this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the sheetnames in ColumnC like this:

```
Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3
```

(ie. separated using the "pipe" character) then you can do something like:

```
'following from finding aCell....
Dim arr
arr = split(aCell.Offset(0,2),"|")
Sheets(arr).Copy '<<if you have a wb you want to copy to then put it here...
```